# I have problems with skype

Tags: skype

My question is, I am trying to make a video call and, 15 seconds after starting it, the web camera flash flashes and freezes the video that receives the other person my picture freezes

Is there any way that I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This question could use a bit more information, but it sounds like you have a problem with you webcam's driver, rather than with Skype itself. Perhaps try re-installing or upgrading it?